# How do I cancel out of the third person view after using the dragonator?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, monster-hunter-3-ultimate

In Monster Hunter 3 Ultimate on the 3DS, when you hit the dragonator there are a few seconds when the screen switches to a third person view. I thought that this was just how it was, but in this video www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEvrdz5IH_0 Rasan4eva immediately switches back to the regular view after hitting the activation button. How does he do that? Is it a gunlance-only thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most cutscenes like that can be skipped.  On your touchscreen during the cutscene, there is a 'Skip' button where the Special Attack/Kick button normally is. The Start button also works I believe.

This skipping is very helpful for the death animation of Caedeus, Jhen Mohran, and other large monsters with high numbers of carves.  It is pretty much necessary to skip if you don't want to miss out on carves.

Comment: Applies to MH4u also

Comment: Thank you! After hundreds of hours of MH3U on the 3DS I have never noticed that "skip" touch area before. It's even in the same spot as on the "proper" cut-scenes. Until now I was trying to faff about in third person view to position myself in the right spot...